# Ember - How to break the build if test coverage fails minimum threshold?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

I want to break the build if coverage drops below certain percentage. Currently test runs and coverage is generated if I run below command.

COVERAGE=true ember test

[image]

but I don't see a way to break the build based on coverage percentage. Request to help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

It is sadly not built-in.
However, some people were successful setting coverage threshold with [Istambul](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc)

I attached a picture of the configuration I found at https://github.com/kategengler/ember-cli-code-coverage/issues/23

[image]

If you are looking to fail the build in a CI/CD pipeline, an easy alternative road would be to:

- use `grep` to parse the generated output that contains the coverage result
- compare the resulting percentage to your threshold with `bc`

*Note: We are using EmberJS at my company but we don't have coverage thresholds configured on emberjs projects . It's configured on React projects tho because Jest has that built-in*

Comment: this helps actually.